# How to create general lists / template lists in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xna-4.0

I have one main class with several inherited members who all overload the same Draw method of the parent class, but have different Initialize methods. Is it somehow possible to use the same list type for every inherited class, and thus be able to iterate through the Draw-methods? I am pretty sure you can do this with templates in C++, but can't seem to find a way to do it in C#. Here is an example:

```
class MainMenu : ExpandingWindow{
   Init(A,B)
   Draw(D)
}

class SideMenu : ExpandingWindow{
   Init(A,B,C)
   Draw(D)
}
```

I want to be able to do:

```
 WindowList List<ExpandingWindow>

 WindowList.Add(new MainMenu)
 WindowList.Add(new SideMenu)

 WindowList[0].Initialize(A,B)
 WindowLIst[1].Initialize(A,B,C)
```

And:

```
 for each window in WindowList{
   window.Draw(D)
 }
```

I am pretty sure I'm missing something here. I do not have to do it in this exact manner, I am rather looking for general way of handling these situations well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
IList<ExpandingWindow> windows = new List<ExpandingWindow>();

// initialize them via constructor
windows.Add(new MainMenu(A, B));    
windows.Add(new SideMenu(A, B, C));

foreach(var window in windows) {
    window.Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If each subclass has a different method, then they don't belong to the interface, and cannot be called without explicit casting (which is a bad thing in OOP).

What you probably want to do is pass parameter to their **constructors**, and then call the interface method with the same signature:

```
class ExpandingWindow
{
     public virtual void Draw(D obj) { ... }
}

public class MainMenu : ExpandingWindow
{
     public MainMenu(A a, B b)
     { 
         // assign MainMenu-specific parameters
     }

     // inherit Draw from the base class,
     // or override it if necessary
}

public class SideMenu : ExpandingWindow
{
     public SideMenu(A a, B b, C c)
     { 
         // assign SideMenu-specific parameters
     }

     // inherit Draw from the base class,
     // or override it if necessary
     public override Draw(D d)
     {
         // some side-menu specific stuff
         d.DoStuff();

         // call the base method after that
         base.Draw(d);
     }
}
```

You will then pass specific parameters when **creating** concrete instances (because at this time you must know which class you are instantiating anyway):

```
List<ExpandingWindow> windows = new List<ExpandingWindow>();

windows.Add(new MainMenu(a, b));
windows.Add(new SideMenu(a, b, c));

foreach (var w in windows)
   w.Draw(d);
```

Comment: I'm glad you bring that up, because I though the exact same thing! :) I did try it though, and I stumbled onto another problem. Having:
     MainMenu(A,B,C)
as the constructor, it did not work to write
     list.Add(new MainMenu(A,B,C))
The compiler tells me there are no methods with 3 arguments, which I believe it is... So I must have missed something!

Comment: From your comment, I gave it another try. It seems like I included a void statement in the constructor. I removed the void, and now it worked. Great feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an **abstract** or **virtual** method in the base class `ExpandingWindow`, and then override that method in derived classes.

Another option is to define an IExpandingWindow interface that has one **Draw** method, and implement it in your classes.

Comment: I sounds like Tormod has already done that, but is having problems with creating generic list.

Comment: I have already implemented the Init method as abstract and the Draw as virtual. I might have done it in a bad way though; as of right now I will have to overload the Init method in ExpandingWindow for each different Init method in the inherited classes (due to the different method parameters). Is there any way around this? Will implementing the ExpandingWindows as an interface help?